# Have navigation link at bottom of picture using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get a link to the bottom of a div of my website.
I am using Html & Bootstrap as the main programming languages with a connected css file.
If there are any suggestions on the code below that would be brilliant! Thank you guys

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bootstrap test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>          
        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top transparent" id="navbar">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="images/BlankBack.png" width="80" height="60" alt="">
                </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="aboutus.html">About us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contactus.html">Contact us</a>
                    </li>                        
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--NavBar Ends-->

        <div class="container-fluid" id="image-container" style="background-image: url('images/image.png');">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="booksy-container">
                <a href="testlink" id="booksy-link">Book your appointment here!</a>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
nav#navbar {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8) !important;
  }
  
  nav#navbar ul.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }



div#image-container{
    height: 1920px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#booksy-container {
    /* CSS properties and values go here */
    height: 27.5%;
}

#booksy-link{
    text-align: end;
}
```

[Current layout and where I need the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gydpn.png)

Need the link to go to where the arrow directs in the image above

Comment: Try set the #booksy-link { align-items:flex-end; }
And set nav#navbar ul.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

Comment: Seems to have just set the NavBar to go vertical instead of move the link. Appreciate the idea though!

Comment: Have you tried then without using the flex-direction column?